# Stablebaselines3 interaction with environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

The actions that we get from a policy network or Q network are torch tensors. And the environment is usually in numpy. So my question is: How does stable baselines3 send the actions to the environment?
Does it not break the gradients if we convert a tensor to numpy array? And then how does it get the gradients for backpropagation?

Tried looking for files ppo, onpolicyalgorithm, base algorithm and others. However, could not find it